# Problem with single posts not showing correct category sidebar

Tags: categories, widgets

I'm looking for something very specific: I'm using a plugin called ["Category and Tag Specific Widgets"](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-and-tag-specific-widgets/) to create category-specific html in the sidebar of each category. This only works if I click on the category name (`www.myblog.com/category`), but on a single post (`www.myblog.com/category/post`) it doesn't work...

Is there a way to modify the single.php file so it ties the single posts to the categories?

My permalinks are set to `%category/%postname`

Comment: If you mean [this widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-widgets/), it hasn't been updated in two years. I'd be careful with it. If that isn't it please post a link to the correct plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm using this one: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-and-tag-specific-widgets/ and it works just fine, except for it not showing up in the single posts within a category...

Comment: This plugin hasn't been updated in nearly years also.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you are describing hasn't been updated in nearly two years.

Here is a method to do what you want, in a better way. It lets you use ANY widget on posts in certain categories.

[Content Aware Sidebars](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/content-aware-sidebars/)

> Manage an infinite number of sidebars. Make your WordPress site even
>   more dynamic and boost SEO by controlling what content the sidebars
>   should be displayed with. Creating flexible, dynamic sidebars has
>   never been easier, and no code is needed at all as everything is
>   easily done in the administration panel. No extra database tables or
>   table columns will be added.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, installed it, but has the same problem as the plugin I used before. If I create a sidebar for a specific category, then the sidebar does not show up if you open a single post within that category...

Comment: OK! Got it! Changed the permalink structure to postname only and everything shows up fine now! Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Be sure to click the check mark on solutions that you use.